# Parse delete object from listview android

Tags: java, android, listview, parse-platform

I'm using Parse on app to send pushes to other users who has the app. I want the user to be able to remove already added friend from his list. I've managed to modify some code, but it deletes the first item on the list. How can I modify it to delete just the selected user?

```
                    @Override
                    public void onPositive(MaterialDialog dialog) {
                        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Friend");
                        query.whereEqualTo("user", mCurrentUser);
                        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
                                if (list.size() != 0)
                                    Log.v("TAG", "sizzzze" + list.size());     //Showing 1
                                list.get(0).deleteInBackground(new DeleteCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                                        if (e == null) {
                                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Deleted Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        } else {
                                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Cant Delete Tickle!" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }

                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }
```

**UPDATE:** @haint

```
// Listener for ListView item clicks
private class FriendLongClickListener implements AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        final String friend = mUserFriends.get(position).getString("user");
        new MaterialDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .title("Remove"+" "+mUserFriends.get(position).getUsername().toUpperCase() + "?")
                .content("Do you really want to remove" + " " + mUserFriends.get(position).getUsername().toUpperCase() + " " + "from your friend list?")
                .positiveText(R.string.dialog_yes)
                .negativeText(R.string.dialog_no)
                .callback(new MaterialDialog.ButtonCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPositive(MaterialDialog dialog) {
                        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Friend");
                        query.whereEqualTo("user", mCurrentUser);
                        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
                                if (list.size() != 0)
                                    Log.v("TAG", "sizzzze" + list.size());     //Showing 1
                                list.get(0).deleteInBackground(new DeleteCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                                        if (e == null) {
                                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Deleted Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        } else {
                                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Cant Delete Tickle!" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }

                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }

                        @Override
                    public void onNegative(MaterialDialog dialog) {
                    }
                })
                .show();
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: How do you get `mCurrentUser`?

Comment: @haint  mCurrentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

Comment: Does it work like this: you click on an user in the ListView, a dialog pops up and asks if you want to delete?

Comment: Can I see the code for your adapter and `onItemClick` of ListView ?

Comment: @haint Ok I'll add it.

Answer (score 0):

```
query.whereEqualTo("user", mCurrentUser);
```

Change this to

```
query.whereEqualTo("user", mUserFriends.get(position));
```

or

```
query.whereEqualTo("user", friend);
```

Because I don't know the data type of your adapter so I can only assume those cases.

Comment: Nope, doesn't do anything. 
I thinks something thats got to do with 

 if (list.size() != 0)
                                    Log.v("TAG", "sizzzze" + list.size());     //Showing 1
                                list.get(0).deleteInBackground(new DeleteCallback() {

Comment: basically that line is the problem. You have to get an object from the ListView position - which you didn't - to be the argument for the `where` clause. Figure it out.